# Why was this question closed as off-topic for Stack Overflow when I had the same question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

I came across exactly this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994659/microsoft-httpapi-2-0

And the last comment on the question from Ivan Milosavljevic contained the answer. The reason given for closing:

> closed as off topic by Kev♦ Jul 21 '11 at 12:04
>   Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way, within the scope defined in the faq.

I would have to disagree, I think this is on topic, it's about setting up development environments for both Microsoft tech. (Visual Studio) and PHP (Apache, WAMP).

Maybe this should be reopened—it's in my favorites for sure.

Comment: It belongs on another site, not SO, like SU or SF...even if it was helpful.

Comment: Because it's not on-topic and it was probably determined to be too old to be a candidate for migration to an on-topic site.

Comment: What are SU or SF? Well it's about web development is it not? It's not about programming, that I agree.

Comment: @SébastienRicher, SU is superuser. It's a site on the Stackexchange network... `Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users`. Stackoverflow is more for correcting programming errors, or for other answerable programming questions.

Comment: Dear close voters on *this* question: the "too localized" close reason on Meta does not apply to people inquiring about specific questions on Stack Overflow. That's perfectly allowed, even encouraged. I added the [meta-tag:specific-question] tag, so hold off on the rest of those votes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re-opening network ports has nothing to do with programming, which is the scope of Stack Overflow as per [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). This is not a specific programming problem, nor something that is unique to the programming profession.

Even in light of [Shog's recent insightful blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/), justifying the inclusiveness of a community with regard to the types of questions it accepts, this is *still* not one that we want on Stack Overflow. It has nothing at all to do with programming, and the reasoning that "well, programmers sometimes have to open up ports in order to get their *x* to work" is a slippery slope. Programmers have to do all sorts of other things, too, like install an operating system on their machine in order to be able to compile code, but no one wants that to be on topic for Stack Overflow.

Given that this is a systems administration question, rather than a programming one, it could be asked on either [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), depending on whether it's a home machine that you're configuring or one connected to a network. But I suspect that it wasn't migrated there at the time of closing because it's an old question, likely unwanted by the communities behind either of those sites.

Comment: Great answer, I'll keep those two links handy thanks! (And bouh to downvotes, honest question...)